# Perl function to grep a string

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a couple of functions for tailing the logs and grep for a string.
I grep for the string `100.81.2.59:4500', 'dst:172.25.150.190:4500'` .When the function is called the logs are tailed as expected,The above mentioned strings are also present in the logs but the function always returns

```
WARN Not found "string" n ipsecd.log
```

Function:

```
sub tail_logs{

    my ($self)  = @_;
    my $cmd =  'tail -n 500 /a/logs/ipsecd.log | grep NAT';
     $self->execute('$cmd');

     if ($self->execute($cmd)) {
        return $self->get_stdout();
      }
     else {
          die " Failed to execute $cmd";
      }
}


sub grep {
     my ($self,$logLines, @strings) = @_;

     for my $string (@strings) {
        if ( $logLines =~ /$string/ ) {
            INFO("Found $string in ipsecd.log");
        }
        else {
            #return false, we cound find $string
            WARN("Not Found $string in ipsecd.log");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    # found all strings in the $loglines, return true.
    return 1;

}
```

Function call :

```
my @checkStrings = ('100.81.2.59:4500', 'dst:172.25.150.190:4500');

   $self->{'log'} = $self->{'log_obj'}->tail_logs();

   $self->{'log_verify'}= $self->{'log_obj'}->grep($self->{'log'}, @checkStrings);

     if ( $self->{'log_verify'} ) {
        $self->assert(
          $self->{'log_verify'},
          'Found info in ipsecd.logs'
       );
```

Loglines

```
[04-15 21:17:04.614251 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:04.821548 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.029262 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.237628 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.444636 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). What modules do you use?

Comment: @choroba   I'm not using any perl cpan modules. These two functions are part of a library that i created and i call these two functions from my test script.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1124151

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what libraries you use, but after simplifying your code, I can't replicate the behaviour you describe.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package My::L;

    sub new { bless {}, shift }

    sub tail_logs{
        my $cmd =  "tail -n 5 $0  | grep NAT";
        my $o = `$cmd`;
        return $o
    }


    sub Grep {
         my ($self, $logLines, @strings) = @_;

         for my $string (@strings) {
            if ( $logLines =~ /$string/ ) {
                warn "INFO: Found $string in ipsecd.log";
            } else {
                warn "WARN: Not Found $string in ipsecd.log";
                return 0
            }
        }
        return 1
    }
}

my $self;
$self->{log_obj} = 'My::L'->new;

my @checkStrings = ('100.81.2.59:4500', 'dst:172.25.150.190:4500');

$self->{log} = $self->{log_obj}->tail_logs();
$self->{log_verify} = $self->{log_obj}->Grep($self->{log}, @checkStrings);
warn 'Found info in ipsecd.logs' if $self->{log_verify};

__DATA__
[04-15 21:17:04.614251 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:04.821548 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.029262 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.237628 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
[04-15 21:17:05.444636 (05026) D  ipsec_processor.: 496] processOutbound: IPsec EDP-UDP (NAT-T) packet to destination - src addr:100.81.2.59:4500 dst:172.25.150.190:4500
```

Note that `'$cmd'` does not interpolate the variable, use

```
$self->execute($cmd);
```

without single quotes.

Also note that [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) is a Perl function. Do you really want to name your method the same?

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the PerlMonks thread referenced by @choroba, I suspect this may be your problem:

```
 for my $string (@strings) {
    if ( $logLines =~ /$string/ ) {
```

If my gut feel be aright, the problem here is that you are feeding it a string where a regular expression is expected.

Consider using quotemeta to convert:

```
 for my $string (@strings) {
    my $regex = quotemeta $string;
    if ( $logLines =~ /$regex/ ) {
```

But this is just a guess, as you do not seem to be answering anyone's questions anymore.